# Not all MapIcons get updated on map?

Tags: c#, xaml, maps, win-universal-app, windows-10

Im adding multiple MapIcons to my UWP app MapControl. I want to change the MapIcon size based map zoom level.

This works almost ok, but when I update marker sizes (call UpdatMarkerSizes()) not all MapIcons get new image.

I have around 200 MapIcons in my map, which I try to update. Is this some performance issue or how I should try to update all MapIcons?

Here is how I initially add MapIcons:

```
public void AddMapIcons(IReadOnlyCollection<IItem> items)
{
    var icon = (CurrentMarkerIconSize == MarkerIconSize.Small) ? _markerSmall : _markerNormal;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var stopIcon = new MapIcon
        {
            Location = new Geopoint(item.Location),
            NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            ZIndex = 5,
            CollisionBehaviorDesired = MapElementCollisionBehavior.RemainVisible,
            Image = icon
        };
        MapControl.MapElements.Add(stopIcon);
    }
}
```

And here is my MapIcon Image update functionality, this is called when map zoomlevel is changed.

```
private void UpdatMarkerSizes(MarkerIconSize newSize)
{
    var newImage = (newSize == StopIconSize.Small) ? _markerSmall : _markerNormal;
    foreach (var element in MapControl.MapElements)
    {
        (element as MapIcon).Image = newImage;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I just noticed that if I also update MapIcon NormalizedAnchorPoint, ZIndex and CollisionBehaviorDesired (set same value again), this issue is not so bad. Previously when I updated my markers (UpdatMarkerSizes()) there was always couple of markers which did not get the new image. Now after this update, I get rarely one or two markers which did not get new image.

Updated code:

```
private void UpdatMarkerSizes(MarkerIconSize newSize)
{
    var newImage = (newSize == StopIconSize.Small) ? _markerSmall : _markerNormal;
    foreach (var element in MapControl.MapElements)
    {
        var mapIconElement = element as MapIcon;
        if(mapIconElement != null)
        {
            mapIconElement.Image = newImage;
            mapIconElement.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            mapIconElement.ZIndex = 5;
            mapIconElement.CollisionBehaviorDesired = MapElementCollisionBehavior.RemainVisible;

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I think that my solution in update 1 is good enough for now. I have posted new question which is related to MapIcons and their image updating too: [Dynamically update collection of MapIcons, update process gets out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292543/dynamically-update-collection-of-mapicons-update-process-gets-out-of-sync)

Comment: I'm dynamically rendering XAML to bitmaps and setting them to ~100 markers, which works fine. I guess performance should not be a problem there. But I honestly have no other idea here :/

Comment: It is always a good idea to add a null-check to the `element as MapIcon`, if it is null, your code will throw an exception and could fail silently.

Comment: Added update to question. In my case _markerSmall and _markerNormal are also bitmaps rendered from xaml.

Comment: Agreen with @sibbl, I test your code, it works fine. You can post the code of `StopIconSize.Small`,`_markerSmall` and  `_markerNormal`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think this issue is pretty much solved as in my update 1 but I have very similar issue with MapIcons and dynamically updating them. I have posted new question about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292543/dynamically-update-collection-of-mapicons-update-process-gets-out-of-sync